# How to split string with random numbers and random number of underscores?

Tags: python, list

I want to cut the following string: `0.343___0.2___0.07___0___0` with random numbers and random spaces between numbers, and get the following list: `[0.343, 0.2, 0.07, 0, 0]`. How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried splitting?

Comment: `s.split('_')` if you're using underlines, or `s.split()` if you're using spaces.

Comment: i tried splitting but i get things like that ['0.343','','','0.2','','','0.07 ......]

Comment: omg sorry i used split(' ') and not split(), that's why, thanks !

Comment: a list comprehension combined with split is probably the most pythonic way to do this.

Comment: list comprehension was my first thought to filter out empty strings, but apparently `filter` is much faster.

Answer (score 4):

The most pythonic way to do this is probably:

```
b = [float(x) for x in a.split('_') if x]
```

where `a = '0.343___0.2___0.07___0___0'`

@Paul Rooney:

```
>>a.split('_')
```

gives

```
['0.343', '', '', '0.2', '', '', '0.07', '', '', '0', '', '', '0']
```

which is then filtered to the expected answer

Answer (score 0):

Working in an interactive Python terminal to demonstrate use of the `string.split()` method. Additional filtering with `filter` to remove empty strings. Note that `filter` returns an iterator, so we wrap it in `list` to return a list.

```
>>> s = '0.343___0.2___0.07___0___0'
>>> s.split('_')
['0.343', '', '', '0.2', '', '', '0.07', '', '', '0', '', '', '0']
>>> list(filter(None, s.split('_')))
['0.343', '0.2', '0.07', '0', '0']
```

Another way to filter out empty strings would be to use a list comprehension as so:

```
>>> [x for x in s.split('_') if x]
['0.343', '0.2', '0.07', '0', '0']
```

However, the `filter` method is much faster than list comprehension. If you're going to have to convert to floats as well (sorry, just noticed that was part of the question), then list comprehension is the way to go:

```
>>> [float(x) for x in s.split('_') if x]
[0.343, 0.2, 0.07, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: way to jack my answer...LOL

Comment: Haha, well, you got my vote. Really just wanted to correct my assertion that `filter` was the better way, because it isn't if you are going to have to do list comp anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use [re](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html) to split on one or more occurances of a delimiter in your case `'_'`:

```
>>> import re
>>> str = "0.343___0.2___0.07___0___0"
>>> list(map(float, re.split("_+",str)))
[0.343, 0.2, 0.07, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
source = '0.343___0.2___0.07___0___0'
output = [float(each) for each in re.split(r'_+', source)]
print(output)
```

Comment: Please avoid giving code-only answers, and try to provide some explanation. Others finding this question may not have as much experience with Python as you; help them understand your solution.